# Assertion error when running trying grid search on h2o for deeplearning

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, h2o, grid-search

I get a java.lang.AssertionError when I try to run the tutorial code with my dataset. Can you please let me know where I'm going wrong and how to correct it?

```
response <- "Churn"
predictors <- setdiff(names(churn), response)

hyper_params <- list(
  hidden=list(c(32,32,32),c(64,64)),
  input_dropout_ratio=c(0,0.05),
  rate=c(0.01,0.02),
  rate_annealing=c(1e-8,1e-7,1e-6)
)
grid <- h2o.grid(
  algorithm="deeplearning",
  grid_id="dl_grid", 
  training_frame=churn_training,
  validation_frame=churn_validation, 
  x=predictors, 
  y=response,
  epochs=1,
  stopping_metric="AUTO",     ## Changed this to AUTO for classification
  stopping_tolerance=1e-2,       
  stopping_rounds=2,
  score_validation_samples=10000, 
  score_duty_cycle=0.025,         
  adaptive_rate=F,                
  momentum_start=0.5,             
  momentum_stable=0.9, 
  momentum_ramp=1e7, 
  l1=1e-5,
  l2=1e-5,
  activation=c("Rectifier"),
  max_w2=10,                      
  hyper_params=hyper_params
)
```

EDIT: Here's a snapshot of the data. It is biased in the original as well

https://github.com/sujaydsa/sample_data/blob/master/ex.csv

Comment: can you share your sample data?

Comment: @sandipan link attached

Comment: Ok, I just shutdown and restarted h2o and it seemed to work.

Comment: I think sometimes your client can get out of sync with H2O (e.g. if you've done something with the data from another client, such as Flow), and give those kind of errors. But as you restarted and it is working, there is no way to troubleshoot this now (so I've voted to close).

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem with data having no missing values etc. The fix that seems to work for me is setting `enable_assertions = FALSE` when initializing `h2o`.

```
h2o.init(nthreads = ..., enable_assertions = FALSE)
```